# Effective Mass structure outside first band minimum

Tags: mass, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I wanted to ask: if I would have the electron dispersion function of the first band, which is not parabolic can it be used/(inserted) with the effective mass function, for $\frac{d^2E(k)}{dk^2}$:
$m^* = \hbar^2 * (\frac{d^2E(k)}{dk^2})^{-1}$, if derived twice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The term as you describe it is the effective mass of a carrier in that band and at that k-point. A constant effective mass resulting in a parabolic dispersion is just an approximation. If it's a good or good enough approximation depends on what you need to do.

Comment: Hi @engineer, thank you very much for your reply. I think I might have stated my aim not clear enough, sorry about that. I have an electron dispersion of the first band approximated by a cosine function $E_{cos}(k)$. The aim is to evaluate the effective mass when k gets zero and at which the effective mass becomes infinite. Can I use the second deriviateve of $E_cos(k)$ and plug it in the effective mass of a carrier?

Comment: The 2nd derivative of this cosine function will be proportional to the effective mass. Anything else would just be an approximation.